# Force Disposal of an Inaccessible Static Object

Tags: c#, dll, static, singleton, dispose

Is there a way to force an object to be disposed along with any objects (including static) which it references when that object is in a library / you do not have access to the source?
The library is .Net code - but the dispose method on the presented object does not completely clean up the object (presumably because some singleton's persisted in the background / not available to my code).

The reason I ask is to solve a problem working with the Dynamics AX .Net Business Connector (BC) [ see 
[Dynamics AX 2009 Business Connector Logon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495062/dynamics-ax-2009-business-connector-logon/18497262) ].  Essentially this is a connection object, only the class stores information about the first instance's parameters in some variable which persists for the process lifetime; thus preventing the use of other instances of the object from accepting parameters different to those given to the first instance.

I'm hoping to run some method which will make it look like the process has ended from the point of view of the BC (but not from the rest of my code running in the same process), or to call some dispose/finalize method which is also able to clean up the static information accessible only internally by the BC.